# Javascript div class check onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check onclick if div have one of two different classes added to main div class and if there is no such - give back alert. Here is the example of all possible div's:

```
<div class="mainclass class1"></div>
<div class="mainclass class2"></div>
<div class="mainclass"></div>
```

If I am trying to check for class existence using JS something like,

```
$('.mainclass').click(function () {
    var check1 = $(this).hasClass('class1');
    var check2 = $(this).hasClass('class2');
    if(check1 == false || check2 == false)
                { 
                    alert("Hey, you are clicking empty field!")
                }
});
```

System will always give back alert even if I will click on first two div's. Is there any ways to make proper check of this using JS?

Comment: Its because the condition is fullfilled each time you click on any div :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier to apply these restrictions when selecting the object to be tracked:

```
$('.mainclass').not('.class1, .class2').click(function () {
  alert("Hey, you are clicking empty field!")
});
```

If these classes are indeed added/removed dynamically, again, state your intent directly:

```
$('.mainclass').click(function() {
    if ( $(this).is(':not(.class1, .class2)') ) { 
        alert("Hey, you are clicking empty field!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Or: `.not('.class1, .class2')`. I give +1 but could not be what OP is looking for if classes are added/removed dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Change the operator to `&&` not `||`:

```
$('.mainclass').click(function () {
var check1 = $(this).hasClass('class1');
var check2 = $(this).hasClass('class2');
if(check1 == false && check2 == false)
            { 
                alert("Hey, you are clicking empty field!")
            }
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r74gw/24/)**

Answer (score 1):

You need AND `&&` operator here instead of OR `||`:

```
if(check1 == false && check2 == false)
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DERPF/)**

Answer (score 1):

Just check like this

```
$('.mainclass').click(function () {
    var check1 = $(this).hasClass('class1');
    var check2 = $(this).hasClass('class2');
    if(!check1 && !check2 )
                { 
                    alert("Hey, you are clicking empty field!")
                }
});
```

another Way

```
$('.mainclass').click(function () {

    if(!$(this).hasClass('class1') && !$(this).hasClass('class2'))
         { 
            alert("Hey, you are clicking empty field!")
         }
 });
```